# How to force usage of python 3 in cocotb?

Tags: python, hdl, cocotb

I'm using CocoTB to test my HDL design, but as I understand, it's possible to use it with python2.7 or python3.

In setup.py config file I can see that both are supported :

```
    [...]
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    [...]
```

In endian_swapper test (examples/endian_swapper/tests/test_endian_swapper.py), if I modify a test script to see which version is used :

```
@cocotb.test()
def wavedrom_test(dut):
    """
    Generate a JSON wavedrom diagram of a trace and save it to wavedrom.json
    """
    print("Python version used {}".format(sys.version_info))
```

I can see that python2.7 is used when I launch test with «make» command :

```
Python version used sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

My python3 executable is named ... python3 in fact (debian). Is there a canonical way to force cocotb to use python3 instead of python2 ?

Comment: My workaround is to use a virtualenv.  Make sure you activate the virtualenv before compiling the first time or use make clean to rebuild the .so files against the right version of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try updating the PATH variable. worked for me.
when cocotb looks for python, it looks for it at the folders that are listed at the **PATH** variable.
let say that your python3 full path is at
`/usr/bin/python3`
(you can find python3 full path by `which python3`)
i also added here link to new place in case both python2 and python3 are at the same folder...

```
> python -V
Python 2.7.17
> ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /home/$USER/python
> export PATH="/home/$USER:$PATH"
> python -V
Python 3.6.9
```

Comment: Thanks lisrael1, your solution is better than mine. You don't have to compile other python3 than the one in your distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a proper way to do it.

First download the last version of python on the official website :

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/Python-3.7.4.tar.xz
```

Then unflat it and configure it **with the option --enable-shared**

```
$ tar -Jxvf Python-3.7.4.tar.xz
$ cd Python-3.7.4
$ ./configure --enable-shared
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Once installed go to your cocotb test directory then install virtual environment :

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 envp37
$ source envp37/bin/activate
$ python -m pip install cocotb
```

Then you can launch your cocotb test environment with traditional make :

```
$ make
```

Dectivate the python environment with :

```
$ deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions on [linuxconfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux), thanks to [themperek](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/issues/888). But it's not exactly what I want.

The alias solution doesn't work for me. The update-alternative works but only with «official» python3 installed on debian. I can't use an alternative (3.7) manually installed.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   0         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.4   1         manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
$ make clean;make
0.00ns INFO     Running on Icarus Verilog version 11.0 (devel)
0.00ns INFO     Python interpreter initialised and cocotb loaded!
0.00ns INFO     Running tests with Cocotb v1.0.1 from /opt/cocotb
0.00ns INFO     Seeding Python random module with 1554105931
0.00ns INFO     Found test test_ttl.ttl_test
0.00ns INFO     Running test 1/1: ttl_test
0.00ns INFO     Starting test: "ttl_test"
                Description:  simple ttl test function 
[...]
3.4.2 (default, Feb  7 2019, 06:11:23) 
[...]
```